# Realm out on sync (TimerTask and UI Thread)

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

Hi I have a Service running on my android application.
In that Service I have a `TimerTask`, I'm having problems syncing the data being save on the main UI Thread  and the `TimerTask` running every 5 seconds.

Example

> UI Thread - 100 Records
>
> TimerTask Thread - 0 Records

Every time the `TimeTask` I do close the Realm instance on that Thread trying to get an updated instance on the next execution.

I seem that the close option do not intermediately remove the instance from the cache so the next time I do `Realm.getInstance()` it provide the same as before.

Any idea on how to have both Threads with the same data at the moment of running the `TimerTask`?

Comment: Realm, by default provides synchronised data across multiple threads, as long as you don't make a copy of the results, add a changeListener and work with LIVE data. You don't have to close and open Realm again, as long as both the threads are using same Realm database file. Share more code for more details.

Comment: @VirajTank  I think TimerTask is a non-looper background thread thread though, so it does not auto-synchronize.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Aha, true missed that part, but it should still work upon a new query, problem seems like something else.

Comment: @VirajTank nah, his background thread doesn't auto-update, so the cache doesn't increment version. He could for example do it in a transaction and then he'd see the latest data tho

Comment: As @EpicPandaForce suggest opening a transaction on TimeTask did the trick for me. I didn't try changeLister  as i do not react base on data update and instead i do check allway base on the TimerTask schedule.  Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack you can do which works in 1.1.1 and 1.2.0 (it'll break in 2.0.0 later, but hey), which forces the newly opened Realm to be the latest instance -

You could force the update on the local thread through the `HandlerController` associated with the Realm instance using package-internal stuff

```
package io.realm;

public class RealmRefresh {
    public static void refreshRealm(Realm realm) {
        Message message = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = HandlerControllerConstants.LOCAL_COMMIT;
        realm.handlerController.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

And then call

```
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmRefresh.refreshRealm(mRealm);
    //...
    realm.close();
```